# iText7 strategy for limiting memory consumption of PdfFont

Tags: itext, itext7

most of the iText7 examples refer to the use of `PdfFontFactory.createFont()` to get handles to PdfFont instances for text operations. With moderation, this is fine...but PdfFont is a pretty heavy-weight object (PdfEncoding) that doesn't seem to go away until the PdfDocument is closed.  So the following innocent block is gonna gobble up memory:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someLargeNumber; i++) {
    list.add(
        new ListItem("never gonna give")
        .setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont("Helvetica-Oblique"))
    )
}
```

a trivial attempt at a solution using statics failed because it appears PdfFont instances cannot be used across more than one PdfDocument.  And because my *actual* case is more complex than the example above, i don't want to have to pass a bunch of PdfFont references across a pretty deep stack.

1. in the iText7 API, there's no way to iterate over existing PdfFont's for the PdfDocument (is there?)
2. is the rule for PdfFont usage simply that a) it can be used as many times as you want b) within a single PdfDocument instance

(i.e. is a possible solution here to simply cache PdfFont instances using a PdfDocument + PdfFontProgram key?)

Comment: the cacheKey suggested above is a bad idea.  It looks like FontProgram instances are cached in a static Map, meaning a weakRef cache key will always be in use (and as a result will keep the PdfDocument in memory too).  A better approach seems to be a Map of Maps - WeakHashMap<PdfDocument, Map<String, PdfFont>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PdfFonts appear to be cacheable/reusable at the PdfDocument level.  If using a WeakHashMap as the cache, both the Keys and Values need to be weak refs.  for example

```
private static WeakHashMap<PdfDocument, Map<String, WeakReference<PdfFont>>> fontCache = new WeakHashMap<>();

public static synchronized PdfFont createFont(PdfDocument forDocument, String path) throws IOException {
    Map<String, WeakReference<PdfFont>> documentFontMap = fontCache.get(forDocument);
    if (documentFontMap == null) {
        documentFontMap = new HashMap<>();
        fontCache.put(forDocument, documentFontMap);
    }
    WeakReference<PdfFont> font = documentFontMap.get(path);
    if (font == null) {
        font = new WeakReference<>(PdfFontFactory.createFont(path));
        documentFontMap.put(path, font);
    }
    return font.get();
}
```

care should also be taken for iText API that calls PdfFontFactory itself, such as Barcode1D derivatives configured to show a human readable value (i.e. creating a new Barcode1D instance per page w/out calling setFont() will quickly exhaust memory for large documents)